# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException on Windows store app

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm a new on windows 8 store app development, I got annoying problem with this IDE first time after I installed it, everything works well but on the time I got this exception event there are no error on my code. I always got it with different number of exception but the message is completely same. Here are the picture :
[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

[image: picture 3]

what should I do to fix this thing?? I need your help, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I received the same exception after updating to VS 13 Update 3. This solution worked for me:

Go to `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache` and delete all the contents in that folder.

Source: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797072/designer-crashes-in-visual-studio-2013-with-system-runtime-remoting-remotingexception

Answer (score 1):

Try running Blend as an administrator. It sounds a bit like [this issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728500/xaml-designer-in-metro-app-project-doesnt-come-up-unhandled-remotingexception).

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a Windows 8 Store application, keep in mind that the System.Runtime.Remoting APIs are not available in WinRT.  See MSDN for a listing of all the .NET APIs that are supported here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx.

Try removing the remoting code and see if this resolves the problem.

Comment: There are no remoting code as well, I just build a simple hello world app and it's happen, this exception happen when I'm in designer tab and scrolling the designer horizontally or vertically, the it's freeze and the exception appear,

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when I started using a static object variable, where the object loaded images from resource. Somehow this tripped up Blend (perhaps garbage collection with static variables was getting confused).

To fix it I just moved that static object variable inside my Application class as a non-static member and accessed it via a public accessor function.

UPDATE - I also ran into this when one of my DependencyObject implementations was causing a stack overflow, updating one property when another changes and vice versa... Look for stack overflows.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had this, right now. The reproducible cause was a crash of the Display-Driver triggered by my code. As this might only be the Display-Drivers fault, it might just needs fixing in the Display-Driver - for the meantime you can try to find the location causing the Display-Driver to crash and do a workaround. But the Display-Driver should not crash, whatever you throw at it. I see strange colours and splits in your screenshots. So I assume something makes your Display-Driver crash also.

Answer (score 0):

I have been receiving the same error after updating Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 to Update 3

Designer works with a new project but removing the code in old projects does not work.

Deleting all folders in C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache worked for me...

Answer (score -1):

The workaround posted by @pcnThird doesn't work anymore. The issue was resolved in Update 1 and subsequently in the latest Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.